# How do I display the values to textfield when using formik?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, formik

I have some trouble displaying existing values in the textfield. I have following dialog where I can add user or update the existing user. When adding new users textfields being empty is fine but when editing it could be great to show the values. Currently the
customer data comes from aws backend as seen here in the image when opening the dialog for the specific user. I tried adding new initial values the one that is commented out currently but then it messes up the handleSave function.

[image]

```
const customerSchema = Yup.object().shape({
  customer_name: Yup.string().required('Customer name is required'),
  customer_contact_person: Yup.string().required('Customer contact name is required'),
})

const CustomerDialog = ({ id, open, customer, handleSave, handleDelete, handleClose }) => {
  // if customer in null don't render form
  console.log('customer: ', customer)

  // const customerDetails = {
  //   customer_name: customer ? customer[1] : '',
  //   customer_contact_person: customer ? customer[2] : ''
  // }
  return (
    <Dialog id='customer_dialog' open={open} fullWidth={true} maxWidth='sm' onClose={handleClose}>
      {customer && (
        <>
          <DialogTitle>
            {customer[1] ? `Edit ${customer[1]}` : `Add a new customer`}
          </DialogTitle>
          <Formik
            //enableReinitialize
            validateOnMount
            initialValues={customer}
            validationSchema={customerSchema}
            onSubmit={(values, { resetForm }) => handleSave(values, resetForm)}
          >
            <Form id={customer[1] ? 'edit_customer_form' : 'add_customer_form'}>
              <DialogContent>
                <Stack
                  direction='column'
                  justifyContent='center'
                  alignItems='stretch'
                  spacing={2}
                >
                  <Textfield 
                    id={customer[1] ? 'edit_customer_name_field' : 'add_customer_name_field'} 
                    name='customer_name' 
                    label='Customer'
                  />
                  <Textfield
                    id={customer[1] ? 'edit_customer_contact_person' : 'add_customer_contact_person'}
                    name='customer_contact_person'
                    label='Contant person'
                  />
                </Stack>
              </DialogContent>
              <DialogActions>
                {customer[1] ? (
                  <Button
                    id='customer_dialog_delete_button'
                    size='large'
                    variant='contained'
                    sx={{ mt: 3, mb: 2, mr: 34, alignSelf: 'flex-start' }}
                    fullWidth={false}
                    color='error'
                    onClick={handleDelete}
                  >
                    Delete
                  </Button>
                ) : null}
                <ThemeProvider theme={buttonTheme}>
                  <Button
                    id='customer_dialog_cancel_button'
                    size='large'
                    sx={{ mt: 3, mb: 2, alignSelf: 'flex-end' }}
                    fullWidth={false}
                    color='error'
                    onClick={handleClose}
                  >
                    Cancel
                  </Button>
                </ThemeProvider>
                <SubmitButton id='customer_dialog_save_button'>Save</SubmitButton>
              </DialogActions>
            </Form>
          </Formik>
        </>
      )}
    </Dialog>
  )
}
```

What I am expecting to see here in the text field is the values ([1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aDxhz.png), [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/di6Zt.png)) so it's easier to make changes. How do I get these to show?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I managed to figure it out. It seems that I needed to wrap the formik form compoment in

```
{(formik) => (<Form>....rest of the content</<Form>)}
```

And then needed to add following to the textfield

```
 value={formik.values[1]}
 onChange={(e) => {
  formik.handleChange(e)
  formik.setFieldValue(1)
 }}
```

This allowed the value from formik to be shown and then setFieldValue to set new value. Also since this data is going to AWS backend I needed to have only 1 in setFielValue because otherwise payload going to the backend was not correct.